# How to print out the contents of an array non-linearly (e.g.in 4x4 cells)

Tags: c, arrays

I am attempting to print the contents of an array in a non-linear fashion (**not** sequentially). My code currently reads data from a text input, stores the text input data into a 2D array, and then sequentially iterates through the 2D array in 4x4 cells and prints the result to cmd.

**Input file**- test_file.txt:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
```

The current undesired output:

```
001 002 003 004 013 014 015 016 025 026 027 028 037 038 039 040
005 006 007 008 017 018 019 020 029 030 031 032 041 042 043 044
009 010 011 012 021 022 023 024 033 034 035 036 045 046 047 048
```

**The output I am trying to achieve:**

```
01 02 03 04   05 06 07 08   09 10 11 12
13 14 15 16   17 18 19 20   21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28   29 30 31 32   33 34 35 36
37 38 39 40   41 42 43 44   45 46 47 48
```

My code attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int h = 4;          //Height of dataset 
    int w = 12;         //Width of dataset
    int matrix[4][12];  //The 2d matrix where the data is stored 
    int i, j;           //Loop variables
    FILE *f; 
    f = fopen("test_file.txt", "r"); //Input file 
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: cannot open file input", f);
        exit(1);
    }

    //Iterate through the input file stream 
    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            fscanf(f, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Iterate through the 2d array in 4x4 cells 
    for (int ii = 0; ii < h && ii < h; ii += 4)
    {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < w && jj < w; jj += 4)
        {

            for (int i = ii; i < ii + 4 && i < h; i++)
            {
                for (int j = jj; j < jj + 4 && j < w; j++)
                {
                    printf("%.3d ", matrix[i][j]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(f); 

    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

**EDIT:** I unfortunately forgot to mention a key specification; I also would like to be able to vary the cell cize from 4x4 to other sizes e.g., 12x12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution (printing loops only):

```
     for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++) {
            printf("%.2d ", matrix[i][j]);

            if((j + 1) % 4 == 0) printf("   ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Code should be commented or otherwise documented and explained—although this is elementary code, a person asking a question is generally new to the concepts and can benefit from explanation.

Comment: spamming @EricPostpischil ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do as below.

```
//Iterate through the 2d array in 4x4 cells
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
        for (int j = 0; j < w ; j+=4)
        {
                for (int jj = 0; jj < h ; jj++)
                {
                        printf("%.2d ", matrix[i][j+jj]);
                }
                printf("    ");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

or

```
//Iterate through the 2d array in 4x4 cells
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++)
{
        for (int j = 0; j < w ; j++)
        {

                printf("%.2d%s", matrix[i][j], ((j+1)%4 == 0)?"   ":" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
```

---

**Output:**

```
01 02 03 04   05 06 07 08   09 10 11 12
13 14 15 16   17 18 19 20   21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28   29 30 31 32   33 34 35 36
37 38 39 40   41 42 43 44   45 46 47 48
```

Comment: Code should be commented or otherwise documented and explained—although this is elementary code, a person asking a question is generally new to the concepts and can benefit from explanation.

Comment: spamming @EricPostpischil ?

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to **print** it, the following code would do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BLOCK 4
#define COLS 12

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    for(int i = 1; i <= 48; ++i) /* replace this loop with a loop over the actual data to print */
    {
        /* print mtx with columns and blocks
         * insert a leading 0 with format %02i 
         * insert tab e.g. e.g. i == 4,8,12 etc.. for BLOCK=4, or a whitespace otherwise 
         * insert new line e.g. when i == 12, 24, etc... for COLS=12 */
        printf("%02i%s%s", i, (i%BLOCK==0) ? "\t" : " ", (i%COLS==0) ? "\n" : "");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1ca5b8796aea7224

Comment: `#include <cstdio>` is not C code. There is no need to kludge a leading 0; `%02i` tells `printf` to format a field of at least two characters with a leading zero if needed. Code should be commented or otherwise documented and explained—although this is elementary code, a person asking a question is generally new to the concepts and can benefit from explanation.